# Regular expression matching http(s)/ftp at the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to get my head around this. Basically, I am trying to verify user input, a URL, to make sure the protocol is either typed in by the user or inserted if it doesn't start with either http(s)/ftp://.

Do not mind the insertion part nor validation the URL itself. I have a separate procedure that does that.

I want to match all of the following at the beginning of the string only:

- h
- ht
- http
- http:
- http:/
- http://
- http://google.com
- https
- https:
- https:/
- https://
- https://mediatemple.net
- https://www.google.ie/search?q=Mary+Seacole&oi=ddle&ct=celebrating-mary-seacole-5096510879432704-hp&hl=en-GB
- f
- ft
- ftp
- ftp:
- ftp:/
- ftp://
- ftp://www.example.org/my-house

But at the same time I do not want it to match something like:

- host
- httgoo
- http:/\abc
- fog
- ftp:example

I am playing around with the following `([https://]|[ftp://])` and it's matching things almost the way I want.

My problem is restricting the regex to match only from the start of the string.

#### Update

First of all thanks for linking the article just the thing I was trying to find before posting my question.

I was trying to avoid having to write a `forEach` or `if/else` or `switch` matching procedure.

```
var patterns = ['https://', 'https:/', 'http://', 'https:', 'http:/', 'ftp://', 'https', 'http:', 'ftp:/', 'http', 'ftp:', 'htt', 'ftp', 'ht', 'ft', 'h', 'f'];
forEach(patterns, function (pattern) {
    // do your atching logic here
});
```

The regex solution suggested didn't work for me either.

```
^f(t(p(:(\/(\/)?)?)?)?)
```

Doesn't match the `f` on its own. Maybe that's just a flaw of  http://regexr.com/ (where I tried to test my regex expressions).

```
(h(t(t(p(s(:(\/(\/?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)|(h(t(t(p(:(\/(\/?)?)?)?)?)?)?)|(f(t(p(:(\/(\/)?)?)?)?)?)
```

Pattern above matches what I am after except the following cases:

- http:
- http:/
- http://
- http://google.com

And matches the following in error:

- host
- httgoo
- http:/\abc
- fog
- ftp:example

And when I say in `error` I mean in error to what I actually want to match.

In any case the article linked above does provide some good direction. So, thanks again for linking.

Comment: Are you okay with non-regex solution?

Comment: Using "hat" '^' means start of string/line, have you tried that?

Comment: @Wisienkas Sorry, yes I tried using the hat ``^`` like so ``^([https://]|[ftp://])`` or ``(^[https://]|[ftp://])`` or ``(^[https://]|^[ftp://])`` or ``([^https://]|[^ftp://])`` but I get undesireble result.

Comment: in regex everything between brackets are character classes. `[word]` doesn't match word, but 1 letter : w,o,r or d

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95993)

Comment: @LukStorms You are correct in saying that [word] will match character by character. Unfortunately, it's the best I could to put together to do the job.

Comment: The following regex will work for all your requests: `/^(h|f)t{0,2}p?s?\:?(\/+[^\\]*)?$/ig`... I would post as an answer, but your question was marked as duplicate for some reason...